# Swift & Core Data: Encoding and decoding arrays of own types

Tags: swift, core-data

It's my first try to encode and decode data with Swift and Core Data. I'm struggling with encoding and decoding arrays of own data types, all of them follwing a certain protocol.

Here's my struct containing the array of `[Instrument]`, where `Instrument` is a protocol implemented in three structs, named `Tool`, `Driver`, and `Adapter`:

```
struct Instruments: Codable { // Telling me: Type 'Instruments' does not confirm to protocol 'Decodable' and 'Encodable'
    var instruments: [Instrument]
    var categories: [InstrumentCategory]

    var instrumentCategories: [String: [Instrument]] {
        Dictionary(
            grouping: instruments,
            by: { $0.category }
        )
    }
...
}
```

This is how my `Instrument` protocol looks like:

```
protocol Instrument: Codable {
    var id: String { get }
    var name: String { get set }
    var category: String { get set }
    var isFavorite: Bool { get set }

    var errorMessages: [String]? { get set }

    mutating func isValid() -> Bool
}
```

And this is how one of the structs following this `Instrument` protocol looks like (`Driver` and `Adapter` look pretty similar):

```
struct Tool: Instrument, Hashable, Codable, Identifiable, Comparable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var category: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
    var profileType: String
    var profileSize: String
    var length: String?
    var driverCouplingId: Int?
    var set: String?
    var location: String?
    var comment: String?

    var errorMessages: [String]?

...
}
```

Compiler tells me already in `Instruments` that:
- Type 'Instruments' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable
-- Protocol requires initialized 'init(from:)' with type 'Decodable'
-- Cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because '[Instrument]' does not conform to 'Decodable'

Same for encoding:
- Type 'Instruments' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
-- Protocol requires function 'encode(to:)' with type 'Encodable'
-- Cannot automatically synthesize 'Encodable' because '[Instrument]' does not conform to 'Encodable'

If I implement these functions, using the `enum CodingKeys: CodingKey` for the variables `instruments` and `categories` in my `Instruments` struct, the compiler has problems with the arrays:

```
enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case instruments, categories
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        instruments = try container.decode([Instrument].self, forKey: .instruments) // Compiler error: Value of protocol type 'Instrument' cannot conform to 'Decodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
        categories = try container.decode([InstrumentCategory].self, forKey: categories) // Compiler error: Cannot convert value of type '[InstrumentCategory]' to expected argument type 'Instruments.CodingKeys'
    }
```

This is where I get completely stuck.

Comment: You cannot encode or decode a protocol. `Codable` requires concrete types. That's exactly what the error message *only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols* means.

Comment: Thanks, @vadian. Will try to add a switch statement for the three concrete types.